# Replace all values in the table with the values from another table/query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a table (table1) dest, which contains 2 rows.  With some query, I change the content of the table1 (src).

Actually, the content of src table can include more or less rows, then in the dest table.

I want to substitute all the rows from the dest table with rows from the src table (query).

I tried to use merge function. But it doesn't delete rows when dest table has rows and src table doesn't have.

```
merge into #table1 as dest
using
(
  select ... col1 --query
) as src
on dest.col1 = src.col1
when matched then
  update set dest.col1 = src.col1
when not matched then
  insert values
         ( src.col1);
```

If src table contains 1 row and dest table - 2 rows, query lefts 2 rows int dest table anyway. But query should left only one row.

Comment: So you want to `DELETE` rows that were in the destination table but not in the source?

Comment: Also, recommend reading: [So, you want to use `MERGE`, eh?](//sqlblog.org/merge).

Comment: Larnu, yes. I want 1) take some table (dst) 2) do some manipulation with the dst table (src table) 3) these manipulations may cause more or less rows then in dst table 4) delete rows those were in the dest table 5) insert all the rows into dest table from src table.

Comment: If you want to replace an entire table with another, as long as both have the same schema, you can use [partition switching](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching) to replace one table with the other almost instantly

Comment: You'll want to look at using the `BY TARGET` and `BY SOURCE` clauses for the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause then.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, thank you. Swith partition - is the ddl statement. In doesn't always work well with snapshot isolation I apply in my transaction. That's why I try to avoid it.

Comment: Larnu, thank you.I hope BY TARGET and BY SOURCE  computes the cases 1) when dest.col1 is null and src.col1 is not null  2)  when dest.col1 is not null and src.col1 is null. And it is able to delete existing rows.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, @AlexIvanov , all the comparisons are in the `ON` clause, and using equals (`=`) against a `NULL` value will result in UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, what you need to do is make use of the `BY TARGET` and `BY SOURCE` causes for `WHEN NOT MATCHED`. With no sample data this is a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SourceTable (ID int,
                              SomeString varchar(10),
                              SomeInt int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.DestinationTable (ID int,
                                   SomeString varchar(10),
                                   SomeInt int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SourceTable
VALUES(1,'abc',123),
      (2,'def',456),
      (3,'ghi',789); --Will be inserted

INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable
VALUES (1,'bcd',123), --Will be updated
       (2,'def',456), --Nothing will change
       (4,'xyz',987); --Will be deleted

GO

MERGE INTO dbo.DestinationTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) DT
USING dbo.SourceTable ST ON DT.ID = ST.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET DT.SomeString = ST.SomeString,
        DT.SomeInt = ST.SomeInt
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(ID,SomeString,SomeInt)
    VALUES(ST.ID,ST.SomeString,ST.SomeInt)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DestinationTable;


GO
DROP TABLE dbo.SourceTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.DestinationTable;
```

Note that I also add the `HOLDLOCK` hint, as recommended in the link I provided earlier: [So, you want to use MERGE , eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge)

Honestly, however, many prefer to use multiple statements for this, known as an "upsert", rather than using a `MERGE`:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE DT
FROM dbo.DestinationTable DT WITH (UPDLOCK,SERIALIZABLE)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.SourceTable ST
                  WHERE ST.ID = DT.ID);

UPDATE DT
SET DT.SomeString = ST.SomeString,
    DT.SomeInt = ST.SomeInt
FROM dbo.DestinationTable DT WITH (UPDLOCK,SERIALIZABLE)
     JOIN dbo.SourceTable ST ON DT.ID = ST.ID;

INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable (ID,SomeString,SomeInt)
SELECT ST.ID,
       ST.SomeString,
       ST.SomeInt
FROM dbo.SourceTable ST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.DestinationTable DT
                  WHERE DT.ID = ST.ID);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score -2):

use `insert overwrite into dest_table select * from source_table;` -- insert-overwrite truncates the target table and inserts all record from source table into it.

Comment: Lauris, thank you. I use SQL Server 2017. When running the query 
insert overwrite into table1 select * from #tbl2, error occurs:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.

Comment: There's no `INSERT OVERWRITE`

Comment: I work with Snowflake mostly. I thought it was common to have the overwrite functionality. Apparently it's not.
Otherwise easiest is to do it in two statements: truncate target table, then insert into target table.